# C#.Net Linq query and null object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception

I have a problem with my linq query. I get a null reference exception. What's wrong with my code? I do null checks but still get an exception.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Math.Round(invoiceData?.Lines?.Sum(x => x.Amount) ?? 0, 2);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate? I know what an nullReferenceException is.

Comment: What if `Amount` is null? Try use `.Sum(v => (decimal?) v.Amount) ?? 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do like:

```
Math.Round(invoiceData?.Lines?.Sum(x => x.Amount ?? 0), 2);
```

Comment: Hi! That won't work. Amount is a decimal and you can't use the null coalescing operator there.

Comment: ah ok ... so maybe try something like: Math.Round(invoiceData?.Lines?.Where(item=>item!=null && item.Amount != null).Sum(x => x.Amount) ?? 0, 2);